# Loop cut is skipping one face in particular

Tags: modeling, mesh

The loop cut is skipping one face in particular (the circled one) and then continuing to the other side. I tried removing doubles and that didn't work. I tried selecting the n-gons and that didn't work. I also tried dissolving the edges and sliding them around but those didn't solve it either. Any suggestions? It looks like there's something blocking it or there's a kink in the mesh but I don't know how it got there. I've been working on the top of the anvil for some time and then I go to the bottom to find this. (And yes, I've checked similar questions but the answers did not help me. All of the solutions were things I've already tried).

Here's the file: [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: you already asked the question, there can be several reasons: your face is a ngon, there's a inner face, you have to remove doubles...

Comment: I've added the file

Comment: Please do not re-ask a question just because you did not like the response to your first question. You can always edit your posts to add more information.

Comment: Lol how about no? And besides I already did that and it didn't work. And the answer I did get I didn't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the parallel set of vertices (circled in red). This is causing a break in the set of faces on which you wish to create loop cut.
[image]

When zoomed in, it looks like this

[image]

So the solution is to dissolve one set of parallel edges, that is not connected to the edge marked in green.(hot Key 'X')

[image]

Once they are dissolved, you will be able to loop cut through those faces.
Checkout the attached blend file in which I dissolved those edges.
[image]